# How can I use generics to make a general-purpose chunking algorithm?

Tags: c#, generics

I have two methods that are structurally pretty similar:

```
  public static List<List<NodeAttribute>> chunkList(List<NodeAttribute> list, int nSize = 30)
    {
        List<List<NodeAttribute>> chunkedList = new List<List<NodeAttribute>>();

        for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i += nSize)
        {
            chunkedList.Add(list.GetRange(i, Math.Min(nSize, list.Count - i)));
        }

        return chunkedList;
    }
```

and

```
    public static List<List<int>> chunkList(List<int> list, int nSize = 30)
    {
        List<List<int>> chunkedList = new List<List<int>>();

        for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i += nSize)
        {
            chunkedList.Add(list.GetRange(i, Math.Min(nSize, list.Count - i)));
        }

        return chunkedList;
    }
```

Ideally, I'd like to have a general-purpose method that can take a List of any type and return a list of lists of that type - rather than just keep adding methods for every object type that I might need. I understand that I can use generics to do this, but how do I make the return type the same generic type as the input?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The other answer does a good job of illustrating how to use parametric polymorphism -- you have two methods that are identical structurally and differ only in a type, so you can genericize it by making a method that is parametrized by that type.

However we can also take this opportunity to step back and ask if we can solve a more general problem. Suppose you have a *sequence* -- more general than a *List* -- and you wish to group it into a sequence of sequences. There's no need to limit yourself to lists; you can do this operation on any kind of sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Chunk(
  this IEnumerable<T> items, int size) 
{
  return items
    .Select((item, index) => new { Group = index / size, Item = item })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Group)
    .Select(group => group.Select(g => g.Item));
}
```

If you want it to be a list of lists after all, that's easy enough; change the last line to:

```
    .Select(group => group.Select(g => g.Item).ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Defines the method as generic and then you can declare the arguments and return using the same generic type.

Something like this:

```
public static List<List<T>> ChunkList<T>(List<T> list, int nSize = 30)
{
    List<List<T>> chunkedList = new List<List<T>>();

    for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i += nSize)
    {
        chunkedList.Add(list.GetRange(i, Math.Min(nSize, list.Count - i)));
    }

    return chunkedList;
}
```